# how does redundant if-else help to optimize?

Tags: c, numpy, if-statement, optimization, macros

I am reading the source code of `Python`'s `numpy` library, and found the following snippets. It seems to perform element-wise operations on vectors (`numpy.ndarray`). For example, `numpy.multiply([1,2,3],[4,5,6])` will get the result `[4,10,18]`

```
#define BASE_UNARY_LOOP(tin, tout, op) \
    UNARY_LOOP { \
        const tin in = *(tin *)ip1; \
        tout * out = (tout *)op1; \
        op; \
    }
#define UNARY_LOOP_FAST(tin, tout, op) \
    do { \
    /* condition allows compiler to optimize the generic macro */ \
    if (IS_UNARY_CONT(tin, tout)) { \
        if (args[0] == args[1]) { \
            BASE_UNARY_LOOP(tin, tout, op) \
        } \
        else { \
            BASE_UNARY_LOOP(tin, tout, op) \
        } \
    } \
    else { \
        BASE_UNARY_LOOP(tin, tout, op) \
    } \
    } \
    while (0)
```

It looks very weird to me, especially the comment inside `UNARY_LOOP_FAST`. 
What is going on here by using `if A then X else X` logic to optimize?

Comment: Also, if things are required to be done only once then why `do{ ...}while(0);`?

Comment: @sameerkn do{…}while(0) is common and has a purpose, see [Why use apparently meaningless do-while and if-else statements in C/C++ macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros).

Comment: Maybe it's telling the compiler to consider the special case where the `tout` array is the same as `tin`, eg `np.sin(a, out=a)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This clip is from

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c.src

This particular clip defines looping macros for a single argument `ufunc`, something like `np.abs`.

The comment before this clip is

> /* * loop with contiguous specialization * op should be the code working on `tin in` and * storing the result in `tout * out` * combine with NPY_GCC_OPT_3 to allow autovectorization * should only be used where its worthwhile to avoid code bloat */

`ufunc` design allows usage like `np.sin(a, out=b)`.  Apparently it's telling the compiler to consider the special case where the `tout` array is the same as `tin`, eg `np.sin(a, out=a)`.

Similarly the fast binary ufunc macros allows for identity among three arrays, `np.add(a, b, out=c)`, which could implement it as `c=a+b`, `a += b`, `b+=a`.

---

These timing differences suggest that there is modest amount of optimization in the case where `args[0] == args[1]`

```
In [195]: a=np.ones((100,100))
In [197]: %%timeit b=np.ones((100,100))
     ...: np.sin(a, out=b)
1000 loops, best of 3: 343 µs per loop

In [198]: %%timeit b=np.ones((100,100))
     ...: np.sin(b, out=b)
1000 loops, best of 3: 279 µs per loop
```

Comment: is it possible that time differences result from the latter case does not need to `malloc` new space for b?

Comment: `b` is predefined in both cases.  In any case the times are suggestive, not proof.

Answer (score 2):

Without more context, you can't tell what kind of optimizations are made possible by the `numpy` code snippet, but it's probably similar to this simplified example:

```
#define LOOP(op) for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) op

void f(int *a, int *b, int n, int c) {
  if (c == 1) {
    LOOP(a[i] += b[i] * c);
  }
  else {
    LOOP(a[i] += b[i] * c);
  }
}
```

A modern compiler can [eliminate the multiplication in the first branch](https://godbolt.org/g/tYmpeh). In the example above, you could have simply written `LOOP(a[i] += b[i])` in the first branch, but if the `if` statement is part of another macro taking `op` as parameter, this isn't possible.

The basic idea is to force the compiler to generate code for multiple paths, some of which have preconditions that can be exploited for certain optimizations.

Comment: I would think that the branch itself is far more expensive than the multiplication operation.

Comment: But the branch is only done once.  The multiplication many times, after branching.